# Execute php code in WordPress Post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

all

I need to write some php code in wordpress post and i found the solution on this http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/execute-php-in-wordpress-post-page-and-widget-sidebar/
using phpexec plugin.

But the old question as if i am switching between html editor to  visual (wysiwyg) editor,it will change my php code also html :(

So what is solution for this, i do not want to disable my wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no when you switch between visual and html editor, it will not change

Answer (score 1):

you can use this plugin if you want to execute some php code in your post or page this plugin is free 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/